# Split unstructured multiline text

Tags: python, parsing

I have a [semi]structured text file that has various heading.  One particular heading has multiple lines.  There can be carriage returns and page breaks in the file that fall under that required heading.  The value of the Recipients need to be added to a list.

The file can look like this:

```
Id
1236547852012

Time
2017-05-01

Author 
mary jane (123654789)

Recipients

peter paul (987456789)

jane jackson (74125896)

Id

2017050145698

Time
2017-04-30

Author
jane jackson (74125896)

Recipients
peter paul (987456789)
\n\r
\n\r

janet jackson (74125896)

fran mckensie (85214796)
\n\r

walter wood (745896369)

Id

4569632587

Time
2017-04-29\n\r

Author 

mary jane (123654789)

Recipients

peter paul (987456789)

jane jackson (74125896)
```

My output for each message requires a recipient list and it needs to look like this

```
[987456789, 74125896]

[987456789, 74125896, 85214796, 745896369]

[987456789, 74125896]
```

My code:

```
recipientList = []

with open(inputFile, 'rb') as f:

    for line in f:

        if 'Recipients' in line:
        #did this b/c recipient id would be on same line 
            lineparts = line.split(' ') 
                if len(lineparts) == 3:
                    recipient = line.strip()
                    recipientId = recipient.split('(',1)[1].replace(')','').strip()
                    recipientList.append(recipientId)

                     nextRecip = next(f).strip()
                     if nextRecip:
                         recipID = nextRecip.split('(',1)[1].replace(')','').strip()
                         recipientList.append(nextRecip)

                    anotherRecip = next(f).strip()
                    if anotherRecip:
                        recipID2 = anotherRecip.split('(',1)[1].replace(')','').strip()
                        recipientList.append(recipID2)

                if len(lineparts) == 2: #recipient on following line
                    nxtRecipient = next(f).strip()
                    if nxtRecipient:
                        nxtRecipID = nxtRecipient.split('(',1)[1].replace(')','').strip()
                        recipientList.append(nxtRecipent)
```

How can I continue to capture recipientIDs, without constantly typing next(f). I wanted to account for any possible number of recipients it can be from 1 - n; and possible page breaks that have titles like:

```
Recipients peter paul (987456789)

jane jackson (74125896)

PAGE 2

walter woods(745896369)
```

..and unknown amount of carriage returns between the recipients within the Recipients list.  I hope this isn't too confusing.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that an empty line, or several, is the record separator?

Comment: Incidentally, you seem to be attempting to read your file as text, but you're opening it at binary.  You probably want `open(inputFile, 'r')`, not `open(inputFile, 'rb')`.

Comment: Yes there can be n numbers of empty line and record separators.

Comment: So, does your input file always have a line with nothing but "Id", "Time", "Author" and "Recipients", in that order?  And does the page break always start with "PAGE "?

Comment: The input file always has a line with Id, Time, Author, and Recipients.  The problem is - 'sometimes' the actual Id, time, author, recipient values (with parenthesis) may appear on that line as well.